# Toggle CNAME entries using PHP?

Tags: seo, php, cname

Is it possible with PHP to dynamically toggle CNAME entries? For example I have two mirrors with media to be served on my website. Mirror 1 has a monthly bandwidth cap so upon reaching it I want to automatically toggle to mirror 2.

I want to use CNAME because the resulting urls appear to be identical to search engines, an SEO friendly approach. If there are SEO friendly alternatives I'd like to hear them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on what options you have with the DNS server software you are using. Do you host your own DNS servers, or is that being provided for you by the hosting company you're using? If you're using your own DNS servers, you can script away using PHP, bash, Powershell, etc. If not, you're depending on whatever option your hosting company provides.